# Flex TextInput restrict: Restrict punctuation

Tags: regex, apache-flex, textinput

I have need to restrict user input. TextInput should restrict all special characters and punctuation. Any other characters are allowed. In java there is a regex patter:

```
replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "_")
```

Is there something similar in actionscript?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [restrict property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#restrict):

```
<s:TextInput restrict="a-z0-9" />
```

Comment: How about scandinavian characters (äöå...)?

Comment: If you were to actually *look at the documentation*, you can always specify by unicode characters or just exclude the punctuation by using `^`.

Comment: Yep i know. But id do not want to set all the special characters individually like maclema answered. So there is no any pattern or hex code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the equivalent of {Punct}

```
string = string.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]/ig, "_");
```

Comment: While I'm not sure this deserves a downvote, J_A_X's answer is correct.